# disabling Cross-Origin Restrictions in Safari on xCode's IOS SIMULATOR (iPad)

Tags: ios, xcode, safari, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

For development purposes, I need to disable the Cross-Origin Restrictions in Safari in XCODE's IOS SIMULATOR (iPad) on my iMac.

In Safari on my iMac, this can be done simply by checking 'Disable Cross-Origin Restrictions' in Menu>Develop. how can i do the same in Safari in XCODE's IOS SIMULATOR (iPad)?

Thanks!

Comment: This really should be an option. Sadly it does not exist. Perhaps there is an app that uses a Safari or Chromium clone that you can install that allows for CORS to be disabled.

Comment: I'm not sure if this was available in earlier versions, but at least for XCode 15.0.1, Safari 17.1, and Simulator running iPhone 14 Pro Max on iOS 16.4, you can disable cross-origin restrictions like this:

With your simulator running, open Safari.
Open the Develop menu and open the developer tools for your simulator.
At the top left, there's an icon that looks like a phone. Click that and click Disable cross-origin restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

*I have tested this solution on macOS v12.6.3 and xCode Simulator v13.1. (Only tested for dev env where site is hosted at localhost)*

**Prerequisites,**

- Enable `Develop` menu on safari by Safari->Preference->Advanced and tick `Show features for web developers` [image]

You can follow below steps to disable CORS on xcode's IOS simulator,

1. Navigate to safari on your IOS simulator.
2. Open safari on your iMac and go to Develop menu and you should be able to see your simulator device. Navigate to that device menu and you should see a menu with list of all the open tabs on your safari browser in simulator device. In here I have only opened google.com. In case if you can't see any tabs opened, try following,

- Navigating to Settings > Safari > Advanced and enable the Web
  Inspector toggle button. (This option might not be available on newer ios versions)
- Make sure the safari browser is on foreground

[image]

3. Click on any of menu items in above, in my case it's `www.google.com`. This will open up a new window, in which you should be able to see logs for your safari browser running in IOS simulator.
4. In Web inspector click on the small mobile icon and then check `Disable cross-origin restrictions.[image]
5. This should disable CORS for localhost sites.